# How to correctly access the ViewModel properties for a condition in a .cshtml

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'm trying to apply a "filter" in a kendo UI grid in which if a property of the ViewModel is true then show the value of cell with a  link address, if false then just show the value without an address.The viewModel for this grid has a property called IsRecorded which it is used as filter for the previously explained.

But for some reason I keep getting the following error just when I run the project and enter to the module where the Kendo Grid is:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.Model.get returned null.

And this is my kendo .cshtml

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonReportViewModel>()
      .Name("Report")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(m => m.Name)
              .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Name" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Name" });

          if (Model.IsRecorded)
          {
              columns.Bound(m => m.Id)
                  .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Id" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Id" })
                  .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"SomeAdress"</a>");
          }
          else
          {
              columns.Bound(m => m.Id)
                  .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Id" }).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Id" });
          };
```

Am I accessing it wrong with the Model class in the if condition? The weird part is that when using Model. it shows me all the properties that the viewmodel has, like it is accessing it correctly but its returning null.
Is the condition implementation right also at all?

Thanks for your Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model.IsRecorded would look at the page model, not the grid model (PersonReportViewModel). A couple of ways to achieve that are shown [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/faq#how-to-apply-conditional-logic-to-column-templates-for-server-bound-grids). I would use a ClientTemplate:

```
columns.Template(t => {}).ClientTemplate(
    "# if (IsRecorded) {#"
  + "<a href=\'SomeAdress'</a>"
  + "# } else { #"
  + @"<span>#=JobId#</span>"
  + "# } #")
.HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Id" })
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Id" })
.Title("Job Id");
```

A console error will occur if you have errors like missing `#` or `{`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually helped. If you or anyone got some time, can you explain me what's going on here in a simpler way? is the { } in Template() the expression that is on ClientTemplate() argument? this methods works together? how do you access IsRecorded property in the if condition without an class/model instance? and whats does the # { directives mean exactly and what are they used for?

Sorry for all these all of a sudden questions, but I'm new to all this ASP MVC, Razor and Kendo ui stuff and I really want to learn and understand it.

Comment: Yeah, Kendo has a learning curve as does MVC Razor. Just keep in mind it all boils down to html and javascript. I spent a lot of time initially looking at the controls and javascript kendo rendered. So kendo has a `Template` that is rendered server side or a ClientTemplate rendered client side. I'm thinking you no longer need the empty Template, but older versions required it before ClientTemplate. Inside a client template you can access your current model either between hashes (#) or within javascript as explained in link above.

Comment: `.Template(t => {})` - this just means don't use a server template. It used to be required to use a ClientTemplate.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the explanation, the link provided it's great since it has a lot of scenarios. So basically you can have two different views in just one sentence of code, one for server side and one for client side. What about this line:

@"<span>#=JobId#</span>"

Is the @ the directive for start a Razor sentence in the middle of the JS code sentence? 

And what about the = in the #=JobId# ? from what you said you are creating a JS sentence inside the <span>, are you accessing the model value of JobId with the = ?

Comment: The @ is a [verbatim prefix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim). Then we are telling kendo to insert the model field JobId inside a span element. You do have to be careful with certain constructs because you have kendo doing it's interpretation as well as razor to html going on. There are some nesting scenarios where you have to tell Kendo to convert the template to HTML: `.ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString()`.